# Best handling for Jackson JSON reader?

Tags: java, json, multithreading, jackson

I'm wrapping the Jackson JSON processors in my own class and I haven't found a definitive thread-safe and performant way to handle sharing instances.

According to the docs, `ObjectMapper`, `ObjectWriter` and `ObjectReader` are all thread-safe and I should use `ObjectWriter` and `ObjectReader` preferentially.

Handling `ObjectWriter` is pretty straight-forward but there's no explicit instructions for `ObjectReader` even on [Jackson Data-bind docs](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) and it is hinting that I should create all my own `ObjectReaders` and cache them. So this is what I've done:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class JacksonEngine extends JsonProcessor {

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer();    
    private Map<Class, ObjectReader> readers = new HashMap<>();

    public String serialize(Object object) throws Exception {
        return writer.writeValueAsString(object);
    }

    public <T> T deserialize(String json, Class<T> classOfT)
            throws Exception {
        if (!readers.containsKey(classOfT)) {
            readers.put(classOfT, mapper.readerFor(classOfT));
        }
        return readers.get(classOfT).readValue(json);
    }

}
```

Is this going to work?

I assume all the generified `Class<T>` that must be reduced to non-generic `Class` for the hashmap key will be OK.

I also assume that the non-atomic `if not present then add` operation to put new `Readers` into the cache in multithreading conditions will not be an issue, except for the potential creation of a redundant reader or two.

Lastly I assume that it's worth doing the caching of `Readers` for sake of performance even though I haven't found any examples online of people doing so.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't actually need `ObjectReader` and `ObjectWriter` here. They are thread-safe and thus can be shared. As you don't share the reader and writer, you can keep it simple:

```
public class JacksonEngine extends JsonProcessor {

    private final static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public String serialize(Object object) throws Exception {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    }

    public <T> T deserialize(String json, Class<T> classOfT)
            throws Exception {
        return mapper.readValue(json, classOfT);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

As OP is concerned about performance when calling `ObjectMapper.readValue()` as it creates everytime a new reader. A look at the source code shows that this is not the case:

```
public <T> T readValue(String content, Class<T> valueType) {
    return (T) _readMapAndClose(_jsonFactory.createParser(content), _typeFactory.constructType(valueType));
} 

protected Object _readMapAndClose(JsonParser p0, JavaType valueType) {
    try {
        Object result;
        // ...
        JsonDeserializer<Object> deser = _findRootDeserializer(ctxt, valueType);
        // ...
        result = deser.deserialize(p, ctxt);
        // ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well keeping it simple obviously has its virtues but I figured it would hurt performance - won't `mapper.readValue()` do `mapper.readerFor(classOfT)` everytime? Caching it would be much quicker surely?

Comment: `ObjectReader` is just an immutable encapsulation of the deserialization config of `ObjectMapper`. `ObjectMapper.readValue()` does not create a reader. It tries to find a root deserializer, delegates to it and returns the result.

Comment: A quick look inside `ObjectMapper` shows it will still do some sort of `typeFactory.constructType(classOfT)` every time. I've refactored the code to cache the `JavaType` from the `typeFactory`, because it looks like Jackson doesn't do that on its own.

Comment: There is a cache for types in `TypeFactory`.

Comment: There is? I didn't see it. Looking at `TypeFactory._fromAny()`.

Comment: See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeFactory.java#L119

Comment: Yes, great. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> can be reused, shared, cached; both because of thread-safety and because instances are relatively light-weight.

[ObjectReader javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader.html)

Your approach is incorrect regardless of whether ObjectReader is thread-safe. Firstly, your fields should be final; without final, if you share `JacksonEngine` across threads, it is possible for its state to not be fully initialized when it is read and will be seen in a corrupt state. Secondly, your assumption about "if not present then add" is also incorrect; even if you do not need atomicity, the use of a `HashMap` may not update for other threads, it may fail every call, you may not see it cached in the HashMap, etc. You're caching without effect.

Just store your ObjectReader in a constant and it should be fine, if that doesn't go, this would be a good place to use `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: Good point about `final` and v. interesting point regarding where the hashmap would be in memory - I had assumed since I want (and forgot to mention) that `JacksonEngine` would be a singleton, that visibility of the hashmap contents would not be restricted to individual CPU caches - even if it is a member variable.

Comment: The fact that it is a singleton has nothing to do with where the map data is cached. I would even go as far as to say that you'd WANT there to be a cache miss so the CPU will go lookup the updated value. If you do not synchronize, the CPU may see updates out of order, or may not see any updates in the first place.

Comment: But `ObjectReaders` need to be cached - and not thread-local either. How do you achieve that? Would a `ConcurrentHashMap` work or do I have to synchronize on it?